# Firewall rules based on Domain name instead of IP address

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall

I am running Guacamole remote desktop gateway test setup to manage access to cloud VM instances.

As I got one strange POC request from one client to restrict Guacamole RDG access to one specific domain which doesn't have static IP, I am out of options. Client might be using services like dynamic DNS to have their domain resolve back to whatever dynamic IP they get.

So basically I have to set inbound Firewall rules in my Guacamole RDG server based on one domain name instead of IP address. 
Apart from basic networking logic, is there any way to achieve this requirement?

I tried below command to set iptables rule based on domain name but upon execution, it actually resolve domain name and apply rule to iptables with resolved IP address.

```bsh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src domain.com --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this easily. There's not only DDNS to consider but also the possibility that the domain name might resolve to multiple addresses.

Comment: Seems very similar to another question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/6714/iptables-allow-dyndns-domain-name-and-auto-update-rules

Comment: To add my two cents worth... I think this is tricky and a little dangerous.  It would effectively give someone else the ability to change your firewall rules because you don't control the domain name in question.

Comment: Having to perform a reverse DNS lookup on every incoming packet would have terrible performance consequences.

Answer (score 13):

`iptables` itself only works with IP addresses, but you can create an ipset-based rule and update the ipset periodically.

```
ipset create allowed hash:ip family inet     # IPv4-only
ipset create allowed6 hash:ip family inet6   # IPv6-only
```

Note that all ipsets will be destroyed upon reboot by default.

The rules will then look like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3128  -m set --match-set allowed src -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3128  -m set --match-set allowed6 src -j ACCEPT
```

*(as a footnote, for FORWARD and OUTPUT chains, `src` will need to be replaced with `dst`)*

Create a script to do domain lookup and update the ipset.

```
#!env /bin/bash

# Domain names to look up
names=("example.com" "example.org")

ipset flush allowed
for name in ${names[@]}; do
    # Look up and add IPv4 addresses (dig may output multiple)
    ip4s=$(dig A +short ${name})
    for ip4 in ${ip4s}; do
        ipset add allowed ${ip4}
    done
    
    # Look up and add IPv6 addresses (dig may output multiple)
    ip6s=$(dig AAAA +short ${name})
    for ip6 in ${ip6s}; do
        ipset add allowed6 ${ip6}
    done
done
```

Add a cronjob to execute the script periodically. For example, every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * root /path/to/myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ipset add allowed $ip
```

did not work for me because `dig` responded with 4 IPs.  Did this instead:

```bash
for n in $ip
do
  ipset add allowed $n
done
```

Answer (score 0):

CSF firewall has this feature embedded. So you can lock down inbound to just a single source even. And have a (cheap, but hopefully secure) dynamic DNS service updating the IP to a given subdomain. CSF will check periodically and change the allowed inbound IP. It works very, very well. Very low maintenance. I use to lock access to a VPS. It seems this should be a very popular thing, but it's very difficult to find much info on it. So was glad to learn about CSF. Which by the way can be configured easily in Webmin. Also it is free. And popular. A little tricky to set up depending on what distro you are using if various paths are different. https://www.configserver.com/cp/csf.html

Comment: I havent tried this tool yet. The domain with dynamic IP is not within my network, so all I have is the domain address, I just want to use that domain address to set rules in CSF to allow inbound traffic to the server that I host. Thanks for the update. I will try this tool and update.